# Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file

Tags: apt

I use 64bit Ubuntu 14.04. When I run `sudo apt-get update` it gives the following error.

```
Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006/ubuntukylin/dists/trusty/Release  
Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file 
(Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)    
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Could anyone tell me how to fix this  problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your Terminal and execute the below command line (to reset the repositories):

```
sudo echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then execute:
 `sudo apt-get update`

Now it should be fixed.

Comment: I copied "sudo echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list" into terminal and run it. But it gave this error "bash: /etc/apt/sources.list: Permission denied". What shall I do?

Comment: OK, you need to type `sudo -i` first, then execute the rest.

Comment: The permission denied error is gone. But after I reset the repositories, I still encounter the error when I execute sudo apt-get update. W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006/ubuntukylin/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Can you post the output of command: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I think I might have solved the problem. I checked sources.list and archive.ubuntukylin.com:10006/ubuntukylin/dists/trusty/Release is not included in this file. But when I open "Software & Update" in System settings, I found this link under "Other Software" tab. After I unchecked it, apt-get update works fine.

Comment: this is probably an incorrect answer, now my pc is not able to install/update softwares [http://askubuntu.com/q/727409/259823]. Please don't try this.

Comment: After trying the above, I get the same error for `universe/binary-amd64/Packages`. What a clusterfuck the updates system is.