# Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file

Tags: apt, updates

I am unable to view any screen in my ubuntu, Also, when i do `apt-get update`.

I get below errors :-

1. Failed to download repository information.
   Check your internet connection

Details

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file),
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored , or old ones used instead.
```

How can i solve the issue.

Answer (score -4):

Please try,

```
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main universe restricted multiverse" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list"
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main universe restricted multiverse"  | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list"
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main universe restricted multiverse"  | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The first lines will reset your repository. Then the update might work.

Comment: After that, you `sources.list`, has only one entry. That's a very dangerous answer.

Comment: I think you meant to use ">>" instead of ">" which will append to the file instead of truncating it before writing each line.

Comment: Test your answer and good luck. -1000

Comment: This answer is still incorrect. Shell redirection takes place before invoking `sudo` and therefore the command will fail since the invoking shell does not have permission to write to the file.

Comment: Adding to what Nathan Osman said, your edit is wrong. Appending the first line doesn't delete what's already present, so it doesn't reset anything. I rolled your answer back to my revision.

Comment: This [ http://askubuntu.com/a/467824/259823 ] ans is also doesn't helpful and probably incorrect, and after using it my pc is now unable to update/install software. I don't have down vote permission till now so unable to do it.