# Probable server issue - unable to apt-get update

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

When I run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I get this error at the end:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The question [How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/q/78951/139574) is similar, but there the error reports `Malformed line 91 in` But this error does not show any erroneous line number.

I have been trying to solve this issue for the last two hours.

- Verified that the `sources.list` has no errors
- Tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/467824/139574) solution and got the same errors.

Finally what worked a few minutes ago was 'selecting the best server' from Synaptic, which finally succeeded in refreshing all the package lists.

But still I am unable to install new softwares. This is a **fresh** installation of **Ubuntu 14.04.3 64-bit** from the [homepage](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).

When I run `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`, I get this response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**sources.list** - stripped out comments

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

---

`apt-cache policy libssl-dev`

```
libssl-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15
  Version table:
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

`apt-cache policy libpq-dev`

```
libpq-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.3.9-0ubuntu0.14.04
  Version table:
     9.3.9-0ubuntu0.14.04 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     9.3.7-0ubuntu0.14.04 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     9.3.4-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: what does `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` say?

Comment: It gives no output

Comment: Unchecked. When it reloads packages I get a similar error: `Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-amd64/packages'`

Comment: how about unchecking restricted? Can you add the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your question?

Comment: @Ron update question with contents of sources.list

Comment: Have you started a `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`?

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libssl-dev; apt-cache policy libpq-dev`

Comment: @A.B. question edited

Comment: And you have started `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: @A.B. I ran update before i tried to install libpq-dev....... But the reason the question puzzles me is that this is a fresh install and the first apt-get update on it fails.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any problems in your (edited) answer. Try this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

And give me a comment. For *all other readers*, this is an answer in progress.

Comment: Both of them installed successfully!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you know why apt wasn't able to resolve the dependency on its own?

Comment: Not in your case. I had a guess. Sometimes the correct error appears only when you install the package, which could not be installed automatically. Your problem may have been temporary. But this need not be so. You could try this to check: `sudo apt-get purge libpq-dev; sudo apt-get autoremove; sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`