# Problem with Software & Updates

Tags: 14.04, updates

***Original Question***

I had a problem as follows:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Then I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467812/unable-to-find-expected-entry-restricted-binary-amd64-packages-in-release-file#_=_) answer.
Followed the steps:

```
sudo -i
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list
```

then executed `sudo apt-get update` and found the problem:

```
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg [72 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release [11.9 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages [14 B]
Fetched 12.0 kB in 0s (22.7 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

and I found 
[image]

Please tell me how to solve it ?

***Update after Neil's answer:***

Following problem occurs

[image]

Comment: Follow these instructions to create a new repository for your system:  http://askubuntu.com/a/192388/231142

Comment: @Terrance thanks for replying, one update: I found that in "Software & Updates" under "Ubuntu Software" tab "download location" was changed, when I revert back it in its original settings then I found the entries in Other Software tab are restored. But the first problem exists i.e. `W:Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: You can maybe create a whole new one by going to https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ then select your country and distro.  Select your branches and updates, then it should give you a way to get a new sources.list file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the corrupted source file and add it back with `software-properties-gtk` Do this by pressing pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>T</kbd>

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/*
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*
```

Then run

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Tick the boxes, change the server to US or to any other server of your choice, then click close.

[image]

[image]

Then click reload.

Wait for it to finish then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: During this relode operation I found ` W:Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file) , E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: updated my question, please check

Comment: Please note: there is no internet connection problem and I am not able to install new software from software center :(

Comment: the problem is not solved till date :(

Comment: @SoumyadipDas updated my answer. sorry for the very slow replay.

Comment: Update on 22 Feb 2017: For the last 6/7 months I didn't faced this problem. I guess its was some temporary problem and solved automatically.