# Salvaging the updates system "Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file"

Tags: apt, software-sources

I am getting this error:

```
W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:
1397BC53640DB551
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release
   Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
```

`/etc/apt/sources.list` contains only this, after trying the available solutions:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse
```

Have tried following [Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467812/unable-to-find-expected-entry-restricted-binary-amd64-packages-in-release-file) and other questions to no avail. How hard is it to fix this mess up?

Will an upgrade to version 16 have any chance of circumventing the issue? I am currently on version 14.04 LTS. Prior upgrades have been painful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apt-key` to download the key from the Ubuntu keyserver, and save it as a trusted key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551
```

When you do this, you are telling your computer that the person who owns the private version of this key is **trusted, just like you trust Ubuntu** to keep your system secure.  Be sure to only add keys of people you know can be trusted to not only provide good builds, but keep their keys safe.

---

```
There is no public key available for the following key IDs: 1397BC53640DB551
```

I normally see this whenever my `apt` has software sources (ie: `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/foo`) which have packages for which I do not have the public key.  This means that someone has signed software and is available via `apt` that I have not set up as a trusted source.

If you [Google '1397BC53640DB551'](https://www.google.com/search?q=1397BC53640DB551&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) you'll find a few other people having similar issues.  However, when I check [Ubuntu's keyserver](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=vindex&search=1397BC53640DB551&fingerprint=on), I don't even see that key.  This makes me think that performing the `apt-key adv` command, you didn't actually import anything (which is fine, I just don't want you worried).

---

I would recommend that you try to [reset your sources.list](https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/13247).  Ubuntu 14.04 is still [maintained until 2019](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS).

Comment: This made no difference, and I now hope others will comment on whether you might be some hacker :( as I doubt how a missing key is related to the original error message.

Comment: I understand your concern.  I'm going to be updating my answer to help you understand why I asked you to do this.

Comment: Now I am certainly more clueless about what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, but it made no difference running that and then `sudo apt-get update'

Comment: I would recommend that you try to [reset your sources.list](http://askubuntu.com/a/192388/13247).

Comment: Ah, at last a solution (the last link you suggested made it). Many thanks!! It all feels so fragile.... I have gone weeks with this problem and could have easily purchased a copy of the latest Windows OS with the time spent on it.

Comment: Keep coming back with good/detailed questions and we'll do our best to help!

Comment: Thanks again, you have the most helpful member on this problem for weeks. I think a flow chart would better serve those troubleshooting those kinds of problems, if AskUbuntu wasn't confined to such a rigid format.